# How to keep two search web parts on same page

Tags: search-results, query-string

I have a search results web part and a content by search web part on the same page. Searching functionality works fine here.

But when I enter the search keyword in search box, search results web part gives proper search result but the content by search web part also changes it's content same as that of search results web part. I want the search result web part work for given search keyword but the content by search web part should remain unaffected by clicking on search button.

Query string `#k=<keyword>` causing both web parts to change. How do I avoid that?